# Client Certificates error in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, client-certificates

I am developing a windows phone 8 application ,in this application I need to connect to a web service and use certificate.

In my request I am trying to use `ClientCertificates` in `HttpWebRequest` but it gives me an error :

> "HttpWebRequest does not contain a definition for ClientCertificates"

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Client certificates aren't supported by .NET classes on Windows Phone.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402533

> You can add a certificate authority to the trusted authorities list, but adding Client SSL certificates is unsupported.

Comment: can you give me any samples links  for adding certificate authority or something

Comment: @RoyYoussef Either point your webbrowser to the url of a .cer file, or mail it to yourself and open it on your phone